# Org Mode & Evil: Prevent editing of hidden text within collapsed subtree

Tags: org-mode, evil

I know that this can be avoided easily, in fact there is a [previous question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/2086/560) here that covered this matter before, but *this only works if we are using Emacs without Evil or using Evil with the* `emacs-state`.

I have this in my `init.el`:

```
  (setq-default org-catch-invisible-edits  'error
                org-ctrl-k-protect-subtree 'error)
```

and *works perfectly fine without Evil*. So, my question is:

How can I make this work with **Evil** without use `emacs-state`?